# Matching users to each other

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

How can I make that on clicking submit button, match the users to each other, like "Secret Santa" rules? You should not be Santa of yourself, and you should not be Santa of someone who is already your Santa. After that I'm gonna filter with `user->groups` (Tags shown on photo)

This is my `.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('List') }}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="">
                 @foreach($users as $user)
                    <div class="users-list" style="padding: 5px 0">
                    <h5>{{ $user->name }}</h5>
                        <p class="badge badge-primary">{{ $user->group }}</p>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
                <input class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And this is my `RegisterController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'group' => $data['group'],
            'wish' => $data['wish'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Do you have the database logic set-up for this? You'll need columns that answer "who is my secret Santa?", and also "who am I secret Santa to?"

Comment: @AndySong As long as i don't know how the scripts work to randomize, i did not try anything